# Excluding header from.csv

Tags: java, csv

I have a .csv file which has header that I would like to be skipped. I get error when the header is present in the .csv file but when it is removed program runs perfectly fine. I would like my code to skip the header and continue on with the process.

What the .csv files looks like:

Make    Model   Speed   Fuel    BaseMPG ScaleFactor Time Travelled

Ford    Mustang 0   20.2    20  0.02    2.3

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   List<Vehicle> cars = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter the file name:");
   String filename = scanner.nextLine();
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(
           filename.trim())));
   String line = "";


   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
       String[] words = line.split(",");


           String make = words[0];
           String model = words[1];
           int currentSpeed = Integer.parseInt(words[2]);
           double fuel = Double.parseDouble(words[3]);
           double baseMpg = Double.parseDouble(words[4]);
           double scaleFactor = Double.parseDouble(words[5]);
           double timeTravelled = Double.parseDouble(words[6]);

           Vehicle car = new Car(fuel, currentSpeed, baseMpg, scaleFactor,
                   make, model, timeTravelled);
           System.out.println(car);
           cars.add(car);


   }

   FileWriter writer=new FileWriter(new File("ProcessedCars.txt"));

   for(Vehicle car:cars)
   {
       writer.write(car.toString());
       writer.flush();
       writer.write("\r\n");

       }

   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Skip the first line in your while loop:

```
boolean skip = true;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  if(skip) {
    skip = false; // Skip only the first line
    continue;
  }
  String[] words = line.split(",");
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at Test.main(Test.java:27)

Comment: What line is line 27?

Comment: It's likely that one line of your input file has less columns than expected. In that case the words array has a length less than 7 and then `words[6]` leads to an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: You should check the actual length of the array with `words.length`.

Comment: Getting the following error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Speed"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
 at Test.main(Test.java:28)

Comment: You should learn to read a stack trace. All necessary information is included. You invoked the method `Integer.parseInt()` with the input string "Speed" and a NumberFormatException was thrown. And you should read the documentation. The doc for [`Integer.parseInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-): "Throws: NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a parsable integer". So your input was "Speed". This is no parsable integer. That is the reason for the exception. It seems you still read the first line.

Comment: You can show your actual code (not as a comment but by editing your question) and mark line 28 so we can try to figure out, what happens. But it would be better for you to learn how to use a debugger, so you can figure out it by yourself. These are very important skills and you should learn them the sooner the better: Read and understand stack traces. Read the documentation. And be able to debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to catch the exception:

```
    try{
        int currentSpeed = Integer.parseInt(words[2]);
        // ...
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        // Failed to parse speed, input is likely a text, like header
    }
```

Or, if you are sure there is a header, just call an extra `readline()` before your loop.

Comment: Why do I get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at Test.main(Test.java:27)